# Find File location of File in Class Library

Tags: c#, .net

I have a situation where I have and XML file that is being used as a configuration file. In my solution I envision having three projects: A WPF project for modifying the file, A console application for the main functionality, and a Class library for handling shared resources and functionality i.e. encryption and the XML file.

The problem is that I am trying to point to the xml file which I have as an embedded resource make changes then save it back to its original location so the it will be ready for the exe to use it but what is happening is that it is saving the file in the bin folder of the WPF project instead.

How do I get location of the originalfile. Seems as if all options I have tried gives me the address of the executing program rather than the file in the class library. I've tried:
"~\filename"
Environment.CurrentDirectory

Comment: Any code you can paste here for us to see and review.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is added as en embedded resource in your project, you should be able to access it simply using `MyProject.File`, or `MyProject.Folder1.Folder2.File` if it is stored under *Folder1/Folder2* in your project.

Comment: The file is an embedded reasource but Typing the name of the Project followed by the folder then the file name is not recognized by the compiler. I tried: [MyProject].[FolderName].[FileName]

Comment: And is I drag the file from solution explorer into my class file it simply gives me the full path as it sits on my computer will not work when I roll the code out

Comment: Did you try `MyProject.FolderName.FileName.extension`?